# Keyboard Setup 87 key

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

[image]

Helo,

Im having some serious issues changing my keyboard. Previously I had a spanish keyboard now i have changed to a us keyboard with 87 keys. I fear that if i dont change it correctly i wont be able to enter my passwords. I am having issues with the @# being written with different key combinations at login or during disk decryption.Any help to set up will be greatly apreciated i have tried to edit /etc/default/keyboard as well as run dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration. I dont dare to reboot the system. But any change I fell could be a disaster since to edit any of these configurations root access is necessary. I am using xubuntu. The new keyboard is a filco majestouch 2.The old one is a logistec internet pro keyboard.In the picture below it looks like the 101/104 is the new keyboard while the old one is not represented it does have a alt gr key.

Thanks,

Comment: It's difficult to help for anyone who doesn't happen to have exactly that keyboard. I'd say you need to give it a try by rebooting. Maybe change your password to something simple before you do.

Comment: But is it possible to have the keyboard work at all? Since it has keys I don’t know if it is possible.

Comment: It's a decent question. `localectl list-x11-keymap-models` shows that Ubuntu 22.04 even recognizes no 87-key model.